# How do I create a tap moveable control in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I wrote a UserControl in WinRT and I want to make it moveable with a finger.
When I move it using a pen or mouse it is still moving but not when i use a finger.
The PointerMoved is not triggert when I use a finger.

Here is the simple xaml:

```
<UserControl>
    <Rectangle PointerPressed="PointerPressed" PointerMoved="PointerMoved"/>
</UserControl>
```

and here is the code:

```
private Point position;

void PointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = sender as Rectangle;
    var pointerPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(r);
    position = pointerPoint.Position;
}

void PointerMoved(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Rectangle r = sender as Rectangle;   
    var delta = e.GetCurrentPoint(r).Position;
    r.Margin = new Thickness(r.Margin.Left + delta.X - position.X, r.Margin.Top + delta.Y - position.Y, 0, 0);
}
```

What do I miss here?

Edit:
I am working with Windows 8.1 and VisualStudio 2013.
Maybe it's a new feature^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simpler than you think!

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="White"
    ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY" 
    ManipulationDelta="Rectangle_ManipulationDelta_1" />

private void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta_1(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _Rectangle = sender as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle;
    var _Transform = (_Rectangle.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform)
        ?? (_Rectangle.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform()) as CompositeTransform;
    _Transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    _Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: that was simple and sooperm thnku Jerry Nixon

Comment: That's superb in the 80's I suppose? Sooperm. Hehe.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't sure you can move by pen or mouse because in PointerMoved event you should check the e.Pointer.IsInContact boolean value to ensure you are selected the object when moving. It make your moving action looks better.

Second, Sorry that I don't know why in your machine the PointerMoved is not triggered when uses finger. Anyway it will better if you set the name of your handler function not same as event name.

If you can share more information, we can discuss.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  
This is only a pseudo code.  
In real I am also checking the pointerId and buttonPressed-state etc.  
The event names are also a bit different...  
The only problem I got is that PointerMoved is not fired on my Surface Pro when I am using a finger.
Maybe the event is hidden by gesture recognition or something like that?